# How to solve the cannot resolve method 'put( int , int)' error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a variable that I have declared as an int , I also have a public int method to retrieve the value of this variable as shown below

```
 private static final int  TIME_SPENT = 0 ;

  public int getTimeSpent(){
        return this._timeSpent;
    }
```

However when I write the line of code that save to database I get an error that says **"cannot resolve method put( int , int) "**

```
public void addAppRecord(AppUsageClass appUsageClass) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(APP_NAME, appUsageClass.getName()); 
        values.put(TIME_SPENT, appUsageClass.getTimeSpent()); // line showing error


        db.insert(Usage_Table, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: thats because put(int,int) is not a valid method..click on that to see the various overloaded method you can use

Comment: put(int,int) is nothing it can be put(String key,int)

Comment: after clicking on it as suggested it gives me the option of initializing an array e.g `values.put(TIME_SPENT, new int[]{appUsageClass.getTimeSpent()}); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `ContentValues.put` is `String` no  an `int`. In this case you might want to use the name of the column where you want to store the return value `getTimeSpent()`, in your database instead of an arbitrary string

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will, since put method in contentValues doesnot support (int, int). Please refer this link for supported methods https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html